# Cosa significa "irto" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning

> È un soldato tedesco, *irto* d'armi.

Né il Treccani né il Garzanti riportano un significato adeguato alla frase; almeno per quanto io possa vedere.

Qual è il significato che l'aggettivo vuole conferire al soldato tedesco?

Comment: Sarebbe utile citare la tua fonte.

Comment: Probabilmente un uso figurato del termine ***Irto***: coperto o cosparso di sporgenze aguzze o che sembrano tali: *collina irta di alberi scheletriti* http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/I/irto.shtml

Comment: Un caso famoso in cui "irto" assume il significato riportato da DaG e Josh61 è la poesia [San Martino](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/San_Martino_(poesia)) (di Giosuè Carducci) (primo verso)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Direi che la seconda accezione riportata dal [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/irto/) calzi appieno:

> Determinato da complemento, detto di superficie da cui sporgano punte aguzze: montagna i. di abeti; costa i. di scogli; sentiero, cammino i. di spine (anche in senso fig., alludendo a difficoltà che si frappongono per il raggiungimento di uno scopo, di un ideale). Fig.: impresa i. di ostacoli; discorso i. di citazioni, di cifre, e sim.

Ci viene mostrato un soldato da cui, forse iperbolicamente, spuntano armi in tutte le direzioni.

Comment: Concordo sull'accezione iperbolica del significato che, però, sottolinea la figura.